# Apache Hadoop: Calling from Java application

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, network-programming

I am very green at Hadoop, and i was wondering if there was a way that you could start a job from an external application and then get the results directly into that application.
After i have written a Hadoop MapReduce job and configured it, i would like to call it from an external application on another machine, and have the output of the MapReduce delivered directly into the external application via a stream or object.

*Say, for example, that i would like to run the example wordcount job every time a certain servlet was called on my webserver. How would i do that?*

Is this possible? If so, examples or experience would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [Spring for Apache Hadoop](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/02/29/introducing-spring-hadoop/).

Comment: tibtof: Would that solve the problem of streaming the data into another application. I have yet to see how you can return to anything other than a bunch of files?

Comment: You probably have to use the HDFS api to read the result.

Comment: That is doable. But how do i call a job from an external application, using the API (And not spring)